# Google API（run_flowメソッド）の引数について

Tags: python, python3, google-api, youtube-data-api

以下のサイトを参考に、Youtubeへ動画をアップロードするコードを作成（写経、焼き直し）しています。
参考のコードは、OAuth認証をする箇所（run_flowメソッド）で、argparserのargsを渡していますが、
なぜargsを渡す必要があるのか教えていただけないでしょうか。
（このargsは何に利用されているのでしょうか？）

[YouTubeAPIを利用して動画をアップロードする](https://qiita.com/ny7760/items/5a728fd9e7b40588237c)

#### 質問の意図

モジュール化を検討しており、argsを必要とするモジュールは利用しにくくなるかなと思った次第です。
またrun_flowメソッドの引数にargsを指定せずに呼び出しても、正しく動作しているように見えました。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow
from oauth2client.file import Storage

flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(
    'client_secret_XXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com.json', # ←ファイル名は伏せています
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload',
    message='WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0'
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    storage = Storage('test-oauth2.json')
    args = argparser.parse_args()
    credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, args) # ←このrun_flowメソッドの第３引数は、どのような影響を与えるのでしょうか？
    print(credentials)
```

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/tools.py#L142

Answer (score 0):

コメントありがとうございます。少しずつ読み取ることができてきました。

次の３つの要素が利用されるようです。
どうやら、自サイトを持っているときに有効？なようですので、
一旦省略して進められそうかなと判断できました。

今後、これらのパラメータ渡しが必要となった場合は、
dictで渡し、run_flowメソッドの直前で疑似的にargsオブジェクトを作成する方法を調べていきたいと思います。

- `--auth_host_name`（str, default:localhost）
  OAuth認証中にリダイレクトを処理するためにローカルWebサーバーを実行するときに使用するホスト名。
- `--auth_host_port`（int, default:[8080、8090]）
  OAuth認証中にリダイレクトを処理するためにローカルWebサーバーを実行するときに使用するポート。
  このオプションを繰り返して、値のリストを指定します。
- `-[no]auth_local_webserver`（bool, default:True）
  ローカルWebサーバーを実行して、OAuth認証中にリダイレクトを処理します。